# Are there "differentiable manifolds" that don't admit a $C^1$-structure

Tags: derivatives, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

It is well known that every $C^1$ manifold admits a smooth manifold structure. What if we relax the definition of smooth manifold so the transition maps need only be differentiable? Does every such "differentiable manifold" admit a compatible $C^1$ atlas?

Comment: $C^\infty \subset C^1$. A $C^\infty$ atlas is also a $C^1$ atlas,

Comment: @PaulSinclair I am aware of that. How is that related to my question?

Comment: I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Do you mean a structure, that is not necessary continuously differentiable, but at least differentiable?

Comment: @Eric Yes that is what i mean.

Comment: The [generalized inverse function theorem](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/09/12/the-inverse-function-theorem-for-everywhere-differentiable-maps/) might be relevant. Let $$f(x)= \begin{cases} 3x+x^2\sin(1/x), & x\ne 0 \\ 0, & x=0\end{cases};$$ is there a $C^1$ atlas for a neighborhood of the origin in the graph $y=f(x)$?

Comment: It is likely to be unknown. The usual proof of $C^\infty$ smoothing of $C^1$-manifolds breaks down almost immediately in your setting. You should post this question on mathoverflow.